# Java Handling Multiple Client Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client

What is an efficient way to handle multiple client connections to the same server/ip.

Currently I have a server socket that creates a new thread every time a new players joins the game.

How do I handle the players?  I'm thinking that I can do it via IP address however I do not know how to do that.  Also, as I'm testing on a local connection and how players could use multiple accounts on the same IP this method doesn't seem efficient.

I would like to be able to manage players with the ability to boot them out of the game and modify their accounts.  Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Define 'handle the players', 'manage the players', ...

Comment: "handle multiple client connections to the same server/ip".  I want to be able to close socket connections from the server.  For whichever connection I want.

Comment: The answer to your question is very dependent on what sort of game this is. Does input from each client need to be pulled, dealt with and sent every tick? are you using a udp or tcp socket? will communication be steady or will it come in bursts?

Comment: It needs to be pulled and dealt with yes.  Only sent when needed.  Uh, it's just a Java Socket.  I'm assuming it's TCP.  I'm thinking that since ports are dependent of the socket connection and not the IP location it may be a good way to handle them.

Comment: Closing a socket is just Socket.close(). I still don't see the problem.

Comment: first, implement the observer pattern to notify the server (server worker) about disconnections. the informed server can now update the database and send further (maybe multicasted) information to the clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how I do my networking (feel free to comment if you'd like):

"Master" Server contains the ServerSocket. "Sub" Server deals with the individual clients. As an analogy, consider a restaurant. The "Master Server" is the receptionist. When a client comes in, he takes the client's request and assigns him to a "Sub Server." "Sub Servers" are the waiters. They process individual client requests. Thus, you'd have something like this:

```
public class Server extends Thread {

    final private ServerSocket m_serverSocket;
    final public static int MAX_CLIENTS = 3000;
    final private SubServer[] m_clientConnections = new SubServer[ MAX_CLIENTS ];

    public Server( int port ) throws IOException {
         this.m_serverSocket = new ServerSocket( port );
         start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( !this.interrupted() ) {
             //wait for clients
             Socket connection = this.m_serverSocket.accept();
             assignConnectionToSubServer( connection );
        }
    }

    public void assignConnectionToSubServer( Socket connection ) {
         for ( int i = 0 ; i < MAX_CLIENTS ; i++ ) {

             //find an unassigned subserver (waiter)
             if ( this.m_clientConnections[ i ] == null ) {
                  this.m_clientConnections[ i ] = new SubServer( connection , i );
                  break;
             }
         }
    }

    protected class SubServer extends Thread {

        final private int m_id;
        final private Socket m_connection;

        //you can store additional client properties here if you want, for example:
        private int m_gameRating = 1500;

        public SubServer( Socket connection , int id ) {
            this.m_id = id;
            this.m_connection = connection;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
             while( !this.interrupted() ) {
                 //process a client request
                 //this is for you to implement
             }
        }

        //as an example, if you read String messages from your client,
        //just call this method from the run() method to process the client request
        public void process( String message ) {

        }

        /**
         * terminates the connection with this client (i.e. stops serving him)
         */
        public void close() {
            try {
                 this.m_connection.close();
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                 //ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, with all this, you should be able to serve many clients. If you want to kick the client, just do

```
clientConnection[ i ].close();
```

the id of each client is stored in the SubServer object.

You can store additional properties within each subserver if you want. Once the networking is set up, this is more "normal" like an un-networked program.

Edit:

To answer you questions directly now:

Q. How do I handle the players?

A. You handle the players using the SubServer object. You can define additional methods within the SubServer class to achieve functionality you want. Specifically, if you need to distinguish between users, force them to provide a unique username before they can start playing the game.

Q. I would like to be able to manage players with the ability to boot them out of the game and modify their accounts

A. Boot using the close() method and they will be disconnected from the server. You can specify account properties in the SubServer object, and modify these properties while the Server is running.

Edit:

So now, you might have an ActionListener that observes your JList with all the users

```
public class UserListListener implements ActionListener {

    final private Server m_networking;

    //you need to pass a reference to the server to your listener
    //you may also need to pass a reference to the user interface (JList) to your listener as well
    public UserListListener( Server networking ) {
        this.m_networking = networking;
    }

    public String getSelectedUser() {
        //determine the selected user on the JList
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if ( command.equals( "kick" ) ) {

            //so here, you determine the user that was selected and tell the server to kick him
            server.kick( getSelectedUser() );
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

In the server class

```
public void kick( String username ) {
    for( int i = 0 ; i < MAX_CLIENTS ; i++ ) {
        if ( this.m_clients[ i ].getUsername().equals( username ) {
            this.m_clients[ i ].close();
            this.m_clients[ i ] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this may work very well.  I will try this out :)  Thanks.

Comment: It works very well! However, I have one question.  I am trying to kick users via my server control panel.  In my control panel I have a JList where I can select any of my currently logged in users.  (I get the username from the client when a player signs in).  How do I kick the player via my kick command using your Server class?  Here is my updated code using your class.  http://pastebin.com/ZS7SM1XB  By the way, the String user is being sent by my ControlPanel class as the selected user in the JList.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume you have some sort of listener (e.g. ActionListener) for your control panel? My method is I pass the Server object to the ActionListener constructor. Then, in the ActionListener will have a reference to the Server. In the ActionListener, when you click "kick,"  the ActionListener you'll get an event and the actionPerformed() method executes. From the actionPerformed() method, you can call server.kick(), because your ActionListener now has a reference to the server. (see edits above)

Comment: also, if you feel this answers your question, would you mind accepting it by clicking the check mark to the top left of my answer? Thanks, and glad I could help!

Comment: I will accept it for sure.  However, I have a few more questions.  How do I kick a user using your command when the getSelectedUser is String based?  How does the JList know which users thread is connected to which username in the list?... some sort of IP grabber may be neccessary?

Comment: use a for loop, go through every client, find the one with the given username and boot it. see edits